# Check if data available on input-port

Tags: multithreading, tcp, port, racket, polling

I have a tcp-connection between a server and a client and I'm looking for a way to poll the input-port on the server side. If there is any data available, it should be read and put into a list. I tried putting this inside a thread, but this blocks until it can read something, and this is not what I want. I want the thread to run "in the background". I was wondering if this is possible in racket.

I have following code:

```
(define in '())
(define out '())
(define data '())
(define listener (tcp-listen 8085))

(define (discover)
    (define (loop)
        (if (tcp-accept-ready? listener)
            (begin (let-values (((pi po) (tcp-accept listener)))
                     (set! in pi)
                     (set! out po)
                     (thread (read-thread pi)))
                   (loop))
            'done))
  (loop))

(define (read-thread port)
    (let ((d (read port)))
        (set! data (cons d data)))
    (sleep 2)
    (read-thread port))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `thread` procedure takes a thunk to run in the new thread. Your code is currently doing the reading before the second thread is ever created (and it should be giving you an error about `thread` expecting a procedure`). You probably want this instead:

```
(thread (lambda () (read-thread pi)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to read bytes, or, Racket expressions? (Because if the latter, there's some tension between "wait until you have a complete expression for me" and "but never block".)

Perhaps bytes would be OK, and you were using `read` only because you didn't know about `read-bytes`? If you were using `read-bytes`, you could replace that with [`read-bytes-avail!*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-bytes-avail!%2a%29%29) which returns 0 immediately if no bytes are available to read.

Whereas if you really meant to use `read` to read a complete Racket expression, be aware that `read-bytes-avail!*` could for example return with just `(x` available at the port, because the closing `)` hasn't arrived. In this case, the best way to approach this probably depends on knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish overall. But generally I'd suggest using a `thread` with `read` -- i.e. let Racket's lightweight threads handle "non-blocking" rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: I didn't know about `read-bytes` and `read-bytes-avail!*`, maybe I can use this. But I don't really understand it, how do I use it with an input port? Could you give some code to demonstrate this?

Comment: Actually see Ryan's answer. (When I answered, I didn't notice that you were already using `thread`, but not using it correctly.)